# Copying code to RAM - how to copy multiple functions at a time?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

Although this is related to microcontroller programming it is a common topic of C/C++ pointer and function operations.

I need to execute flash memory programming routine (let's say *reprogram()*) from RAM and it is a simple task. But this function uses flash access functions (say *blockWrite(...)*, *blockErase(...)*) that are by default put on flash while compiling and flashing.

Adding *inline* to function declaration and definition does not help with getting the goal, gcc and optimization options that I'm using simply ignore *inline* and does not expand this function inline.

One of the option I can see is to make these functions nested inside *reprogram()* but they might be part of the library and used from other places as well.

What are the other options except from unwinding them in place manually of course? :-)

EDIT: ok, I can see that I have possibly been misunderstood.

The question is not about how to actually move the code and execute from RAM but rather how to make functions used by this function to be moved as well. The first idea was changing this helper functions to *inline* but the gcc ignored this directive while optimizing.
If I only move *reprogram()* function to RAM it will call the helper function from flash anyway.

Comment: Is this for the purpose of FW upgrade or something like that?

Comment: This isn't something that's addressed by C or C++.  It's down to your specific microcontroller, and the tools you're using for it.

Comment: @Oli: Is it a strict requirement that all questions asked has to be answerable ONLY with something fulfilled by standard C or C++? No questions allowed about inline assembler, or about how to make audio playing on Windows, or how to make OpenGL graphics appear on Linux, since all of those are "not defined by C or C++ standards".

Comment: @MatsPetersson: When the questions are tagged `c` `c++` (and nothing else) then yes.  Questions need to identify what they are about and include the relevant information to make them answerable.  Questions about windows audio should be tagged `windows` `audio`.  This question really needs to include the specific toolchain and microcontroller it is about (and should be tagged such)

Comment: @barakmanos: yes, this is part of in-system firmware update purposes.

Comment: Then you should consider burning the updated firmware to a different address space on your EPROM, and then update the pointer to that new address where needed (in the Boot I suppose).

Answer (score 2):

I have done this (or been part of a team that designed the software for it, at least) sort of thing a few times. There are several approaches, and it really depends on what your overall system design is. There isn't a single solution that can do this, you will have to figure out what is right in your hardware/software combination. But here's a few "hints".

Bear in mind also "failures", e.g. what happens if there is a power-cut or something goes wrong with the programming of the flash.

The general principles are:

1. Either make the code relocatable, hard-code the actual address, or use MMU functionality to "change the address to match the expected address". Putting the code in a separate section (using compiler/tool-chain specific extensions) to allow it to be easily identified.
2. Copy the section of code relevant (the easiest is really to copy "everything"). Make sure you ALSO redirect any interrupt handlers, and so on to operate in RAM [1], that would be part of your normal operations (or disable all interrupts during the actual programming phase).
3. Load a block or two of flash content into RAM, then program into flash.
4. Resume normal operation (e.g. reboot).

Another option is to have two "banks" of flash, that you can, via some selection pin on the CPU, choose which one is where, and use one as your "execute base", and one to "program". This certainly requires the flash to be (at least) two separate chips. The advantage is that you have a "backup" if power goes half-way through the programming (using "half" the flash would also be a solution for this, combined with a "load flash programming code into RAM" solution)

A further option is to have a small boot-loader piece of code that is written in such a way that you can copy it to the RAM, and then from there, load a piece of flash programming code that comes with the actual updated software in a standardized form as a "module". Again, make sure this code takes care of programming interrupts to only call interrupt handlers from RAM, and all code is loaded into RAM, including error handling, exception handling, etc, etc. If the small boot-loader is a separate, protected, block of flash, you again have a good way to "recover".

[1] I actually got called out to a customer when I worked for a hardware company, because their flash programming code was not working right, and they suspected that their processor was broken. It turns out that if your timer interrupt is running "code" in flash that is being reprogrammed, it will do REALLY bizarre things (because the "content" in the flash is now "status codes", which vary depending on the current state of programming, including a "I'm alive bit" that toggles for each read. Meaning that the processor gets all kinds of random "code" to run - weird things happen - but as soon as you stop in the in-circuit emulator, it takes enough microseconds to get stopped and the user type a command to make it "back to normal", so everything looks fine - except you've executed a couple of dozen "bizarre op-codes", and now wonder why you are executing random garbage in the middle of nowhere).

Answer (score 0):

Microprocessors deal with memory addresses, some of those addresses point to RAM and some of those address (I am guessing here) point to executable flash memory. When you create a program, the linker (or later on your OS loader) decide what addresses are assigned to what symbols.

When composing your own binary image, you need to control what addresses are assigned to what functions. This you can do by writing your own linker script. Details of how to do it for GNU ld can be found [here](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/ld/).

Answer (score 0):

To copy functions from Flash into RAM, first profile your system to see if there is any negligible speed difference between Flash and RAM.  Code can be executed in Flash.

The C and C++ languages can give you the address of a function but not its length.  You'll need to get compiler or linker specific information on this topic.

I suggest using sections or regions.  Create a section for functions that need moving to RAM.  Tell your linker or compiler to put the special functions into the section.  You can write code that copies the data from the section in Flash to RAM.  Some IDEs and linkers come with special commands that assist with copying from ROM to RAM.

**Programming Code into Flash**
Most medium to large embedded systems that I worked with, upload the executable into SRAM using Bootloader commands.  The Bootloader is a small application that is copied into SRAM for setting up the system, *and loading applications*.

Essentially, the algorithm is:

1. Erase one or more blocks in the Flash where the code will reside.
2. Unlock the Flash for programming.
3. Write the data from RAM to the Flash, according the Manufacturer's
   algorithm.  Some Flash devices have algorithms for programming large
   blocks.

Set Flash to Read Mode
Verify data was correctly programmed into Flash.